# Waveguide allowed modes | Transverse resonance condition

Tags: optics, maxwell-equations, fiber-optics, waveguide, photonics

Consider a planar waveguide for example. The guiding index is $n_f$, and the cover and substrate indices are $n_c$ and $n_s$ respectively. Let the waveguide propagate along z, and have a height $h$ in the x-direction.

[image]

I understand that to have guided modes, it is necessary that the vector $\beta \in [k_0n_s,k_0n_f]$, where $k_0$ is the incident wave vector. Solving Maxwells equations for this system gives us an eigenvalue equation whose solutions constitute the allowed modes ($\beta$).

When explaining intuitively explain why there are only a discrete number of allowed solutions, the transverse resonance condition is discussed, where the net phase difference of the transverse component ($\kappa$) is $2\pi\nu$ $\forall$ $\nu \in \cal{Z}$.

\begin{equation*}
2k_0n_fh\cos(\theta) - 2\Phi_c - 2\Phi_s = 2\pi\nu
\end{equation*}
where $\theta$ is the angle of incidence, and $2\Phi_s$ and $2\Phi_c$ are the phase difference after reflecting off the substrate and cover respectively.

What I do not understand is that if this isn't the case, we will still have a longitudinal component which will propagate through the structure, and therefore still transmit information. So why is transverse resonance a necessary condition?

**Reference**: Pollock, C. R., & Lipson, M. (2003). Integrated Photonics. doi:10.1007/978-1-4757-5522-0